# How do I override the default Windows Phone theme for my app?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Lets say that, regardless of what color settings the user has, I want my app to have a white background with blue foreground elements, like the Skype app does.

How do I go about that? I've found how I can make elements use the system brushes, but I can't figure out how to change those default brushes. I also can't find where the background color is specified at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library created by Jeff called PhoneThemeManager. You can find the article about the same here: [PhoneThemeManager](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/). Just download it from NuGet and modify your app.xaml.cs file to get Light (white background) theme activated. The code is simple:

```
ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
```

Once you apply the theme, all your pages will have white background. For blue foreground elements, you'll need to create your own styles and apply them to elements. I'll prefer Blend to create design template over here as you'll get WYSIWYG interface. Using system brushes will not help as those will change according to Accent color. Creating your own styles will give you more freedom and control.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [how to apply theme resources to wp8 app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545(v=vs.105).aspx), it describes exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This seems to be the reverse of what I want. This shows how to apply the default theme to custom elements in your app, I want to apply a custom theme to default elements.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way to accomplish this Task is to use Expression Blend.
Expression Blend is most suitable for this purpose as it will provide and intuitive interface.

The Interface is shown below for a WP app (7.1, it applies to WP8 as well)

[image: Screenshot of a WP App]

The interface is easy to use.

- Select an Item on *Objects and Timeline*
- An object is selected and UI updates in middle.
- Now Check the right side for properties. See the *Background* is selected. Select the required color of choice and other properties.

Pros: This applies to various elements including Menu Items, Buttons and all.
Cons: Items such as MessageBox can't be customized this way.